# Vectorising function on subset of dataframe based on other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from a psychology experiment with the time since the beginning of the experiment for each subject, and what I want is to set from that the time since the beginning of each trial for each subject. To do so I'm basically just substracting the minimum time value for each trial/subject to all the values for that same trial/subject.

I'm currently doing it with two for loops, I was just wondering if there's a way   to vectorise it. What I have at the minute:

```
for (s in 1:max(df$Subject)){
  subject <- df[df$Subject==s,]
  for (t in 1:max(subject$TrialId)){
    trial <- subject[subject$TrialId==t,]
    start_offset <- min(trial$timestamp)
    df$timestamp[df$Subject==s & df$TrialId==t] <- df$timestamp[df$Subject==s &
                                                                df$TrialId==t]
                                                     - start_offset
  }
}
```

And what I would like is something like

```
df$timestamp <- df$timestamp - min_per_trial_per_subject(df$timestamp)
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your dataset?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The full dataset is technically on Github, would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Subject, TrialId) %>%
  mutate(modified_timestamp = timestamp - min(timestamp))
```

Should work. If it doesn't, please share a reproducible example so we can test.

Comment: Works just fine! Although you still need to put `df <-` at the beginning of your line (not familiar with the `%>%` notation so didn't know that). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't like to make assumptions about assignment - you might prefer `df_modified <- ...`